# Error: Dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-google-cloud-platform und nginx

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, dns, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy

My purpose is to use nginx as a proxx for another application and I got the error above.

My nginx configurations are showed below and I already unlinked the default nginx configurations but still I got the error :  DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

````
server {
       listen 80 default_server ;
   server_name www.app.staging.bla.blabla;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name www.app.staging.bla.blabla;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/pivot-staging.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/pivot-staging.key;

   location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
   }

}
```

I use nginx as a VM instance on Google cloud and I have two fw rules (allow http and allow ssh access)..

and the OS is ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance !
````

Comment: Your question is offtopic here (and would need some formatting) as not related to programming. Anyway the name `www.pivot.staging.ippen.space` does not resolve on the public DNS (no `A` records) so nothing can work until this is fixed.

Comment: do you mean creating an A record on the VM itself or from GCP service ? can you please provide further details ?

Comment: A records in a DNS server/service

Comment: Your name servers are located at AWS. Unless you have delegated a zone to Google Cloud DNS, you must create the DNS resource record at AWS.